# AspectMock test::double doesn't work in Yii2 tests

Tags: testing, yii2, mocking

When I try to mock anything like so:

```
Test::double(MyService::class, [
    'accept' => true
]);
```

It throws error:

> Call to a member function registerClass() on null

I could not find anything in the internet to help me with this one. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
One step further. I had to update Test/_bootstrap.php with following:

```
$kernel = Kernel::getInstance();
$kernel->init([
    'debug' => true,
    'includePaths' => [__DIR__ . '/../service/'],
    'excludePaths' => [__DIR__],
    'cacheDir'  => '/tmp/aopcache',
]);
```

It still does not work, but at least throws no errors. Any idea how to make AspectMock actually mock stuff?

**SOLUTION**

I figured it out. In your test/_bootstrap.php you must load yii AFTER you configured kernel:

```
$kernel->loadFile(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
```

This can be closed.

Comment: You should add the answer to your question and accept it your own self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In your test/_bootstrap.php you must load yii AFTER you configured kernel:

```
$kernel->loadFile(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
```